# composition of functions - one-way inverse

Tags: functions, inverse-function, function-and-relation-composition

Construct functions $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and $g: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $g \circ f = \textrm{id}_{\mathbb{N}}$ but $f \circ g \neq \textrm{id}_{\mathbb{N}}$. Couldn't think of any... Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x) = x + 1$ and let $g$ be the function defined by $g(0) =0$ and $g(x) = x-1$ if $x > 0$. Then $g(f(x)) = g(x+1) = x$ but $f(g(0))=f(0)=1$.

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention that in my class zero does not count as a natural number.

Comment: @fuzzz Can you change his function slightly to account for that?

Comment: g(x) doesn't seem to be a function. g(1) = g(0) = 0 but functions map each input to a distinct output

Comment: It looks like you make a confusion with the definition of an injective function.

Comment: omg yeah thanks guys lol